# Function header convention/expected style for methods that have blocks as parameters

Tags: objective-c, parameters, callback

I understand that this is more a stylistic question than a technical question (and it's a minor one), but I was wondering whether or not there is a current convention for declaring documentation comments for methods that have blocks as parameters (especially if the block itself takes in parameters).

Since I started developing in Objective-C, whenever I've faced this issue I've done the following:

```
/**
 * This method does some awesome stuff and takes in a completion handler when it is 
 * done. I am wondering how to format the parameters of the completion block that is
 * passed in. I currently do this as I've written below, with the parameters of the
 * callback indented in line with the description of the callback itself.
 *
 * @param completion - callback to be triggered upon success.
 *                     @param (NSArray *) - an array that holds many objects
 *                     @param (SOPost *)  - a post onto StackOverflow
 */
- (void)someMethodWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *, SOPost *))completion {

    /* Function does whatever it's supposed to ... for example ... */
    NSArray *arr = [NSArray new];
    SOPost *post = [SOPost new];
    completion(arr, post);
}
```

This can certainly be applicable to any language (javascript especially), but my above example is in Objective-C because I deal with that the most.

Comment: Is your question about how to format the doc comment?

Comment: Yep! It's for the comment; I called it the "function header", but I guess it's something like "function header description." Specifically, I'm wondering about formatting the parameters of the callback (@param NSArray * and @param SOPost *). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think "function header" should be replaced with "documentation comment".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typedef your block so that it is named meaningfully. The documentation for what the block takes can go there instead.

```
//These blocks are pretty self explanatory but more complicated ones could warrant documentation.
typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(id object);
typedef void(^AsyncLoadingBlock)(CompletionBlock completion);
typedef NSArray*(^FilterBlock)(NSArray *objects);

- (void)someMethodWithCallback:(CallbackBlock)callback; //callback accepts a SomeClass*
- (void)loadStuffWithCallback:(CallbackBlock)callback; //callback accepts an NSArray* of SomeData*
- (NSArray *)arrayByFilteringWithBlock:(FilterBlock)filterBlock //returns a new array filtered using a FilterBlock
```

Comment: Got it; can you stick up an example of the typedef-ing so future viewers can see?

Comment: Ya this seems to be pretty efficient for Objective-C; do you have any experience with using callbacks in Javascript and documenting them there?

Comment: I'm afraid not, please post a new question if you need a comparison with Javascript. Careful though, "language comparison" questions can easily be flagged as "too broad" and down-voted. Better to narrow your question to Javascript only.